# How to get user id and then remove it to get the robot back up and running - Telegram/Python/Telethon?

Tags: python, telegram, telethon, userid

I have a telegram robot that automatically responds (Python/Telethon). If someone clicks on talk to an attendant, it no longer works when another person contacts the robot.

I researched a lot on how I put the user id in the array so that the robot doesn't stop for other people who come in contact at the same time and when I finish the conversation, remove the user id so that the robot comes back. Nothing I've tried has ever worked.

this is a part of the code. Could someone help, please?
Sorry for English, it's not my primary language.

...

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(incoming=True))
    async def _(event):
      if event.is_private:
        if event.message.message == '1':
          await event.reply('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

This is an option I found on the internet, but I couldn't find how to remove the user-id later to work again and read other people at the same time.

`from_ = await event.client.get_entity(event.from_id)`

Answer (score 0):

To be able to control users at the same time
Must be somewhere (it does not matter, database or even a variable in the dictionary)
For example, save that user A is talking to user B.

For example, with a dictionary

```
talks = {'A': 'B', 'B': 'A'}
```

If the call ends, the keys and values are removed from the dictionary